# How to configure DataTables to use Ajax for pagination after already initalizing DataTables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, pagination

I have a website that already has a lot of pages using the DataTables library. On the back end, I'm returning all the data from the database. The data is now growing and I'd like to use the pagination API by DataTables.

I do not want to initialize the tables with the Ajax URL right off the bat because that would mean refactoring my code. I'm using templates which I pass models to so it would be a pain to refactor.

What I want to do is have the first request return the page with an initial load of data and then configure DataTables (which would have already been initialized) to now load subsequent data through ajax.

Looking at this https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url(), it seems you have to have configured the `ajax` property first to use it.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What you describe sounds like [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). Is that an option?

Comment: @andrewjames I'm looking at it but it seems like I have to implement searches etc? OMG. It's sending a huge request with parameters in the URL. Is there a way to just configure the data to be pulled from the serve and leave out all the filtering to DT?

Comment: Basically, the server take over responsibility for paging, sorting, filtering - yes. I understand that could be a re-write for you. I suspect there is a simpler way, as you suggest - but I think we'd need a representative sample of your code and data to advise on that.

Comment: Most of the rows have custom attributes attached to them through the templating engine I'm using. The engine also provides methods for sanitizing input to all the data I'm rendering in the views, so it means I'd have to duplicate a lot of stuff . Plus it's just not ideal to have requests when the user types something in the search box